# Having coming code in class for two class that have different base class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have

```
classA : MPMoviePlayerViewController
classB : UIViewController
```

Both classA and classB have a lot of same code that is duplicated. Which I want to put in one class but as the classes inherit from two different classes it is not possible to make a common base class. Any way to solve this problem

Thanks in advance!

Comment: move comman code in some `NSObject` class and access from that, if its only functional methods.

Comment: you mean creating a static class?

Comment: Not a static class, but a subclass of NSObject and make all methods as class method so that you can access it without creating object. I believe its more clear.

Comment: In this case I usually prefer use composition approach instead of inheritance. You could create one class where use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` or `UIViewController` as `property`.

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: If inheritance is the only way to achieve the result, my solution doesn't helpful, otherwise you could try this:
Write a `classC` which have same code. And make `property` for `classC` with on of base class, e.g. `UIViewController`. And when you create object of `classC` set appropriate object into this property (object of each controller). If this is not enough for your task you could also create classes: `classA` for using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and `classB` for using.  Which are subclasses of `classC` and implement any specific function for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can create category on UIViewController, since both class ultimately inherits from them. As long as you don't need to add stored variable that fine (category can do that too, but it's a bit trickier).

Or you can make both class conforming a protocol and use a third class that would do the common stuff, and you inject the classA or classB instance when needed.